# Parabolic PDE whose solution is a product of lower dimensional solutions?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, parabolic-pde

Consider the partial differential equation:

$$ \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n s_i\bigg) \Delta \Phi=nu \Phi_u $$

for $\Phi(u,s_1,s_2,\cdot\cdot\cdot,s_n).$

This is a linear parabolic partial differential equation reminiscent of the heat equation on $\Bbb R^n.$

I would like a solution that is a product of one dimensional solutions: $ \Phi(u,s_1,s_2,\cdot\cdot\cdot,s_n)=\Phi(u,s_1)\cdot \Phi(u,s_2)\cdot\cdot\cdot \Phi(u,s_n).$

> Is this possible?

I'm not dealing with any boundary conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a possibility. Let's try the ansatz
$$
\Phi(u,s_1,s_2,\cdot\cdot\cdot,s_n)=e^{\phi(u)\sum_{i=1}^ns_i}
=\prod_{i=1}^ne^{\phi(u)s_i}. \tag{1}
$$
Substituting $(1)$ in the PDE, we obtain an ODE for $\phi(u)$:
$$
\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n s_i\bigg) n\phi^2(u) e^{\phi(u)\sum_{i=1}^ns_i}
=nu \phi'(u)\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n s_i\bigg)e^{\phi(u)\sum_{i=1}^ns_i} 
$$
$$
\Rightarrow u\phi'(u)=\phi^2(u). \tag{2}
$$
The solution to $(2)$ is
$$
\phi(u)=-\frac{1}{C+\ln|u|}, \tag{3}
$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. We conclude that yes, the PDE has a solution that is a product of one-dimensional solutions.

---

P.S. - In addition to the solution presented above, there are some trivial solutions satisfying the condition $\Phi(u,s_1,\ldots,s_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n\Phi(u,s_i)$: (a) $\Phi=0$, (b) $\Phi=1$, and (c) if $n$ is odd, $\Phi=-1$.

Comment: $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\Phi(t,b)=\pm \frac{b}{t}\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\Phi(t,b)$$

Is there some reason or intuition that $\Phi(t,b)$ and its reciprocal satisfy that backwards heat equation and heat equation resp.?